# Dependent p:selectOneMenu Population of values

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0 with Primefaces 3.4.2

I have two `p:selectOneMenu`, first one parent and second child, based on parent value, child component gets populated.

Parent `p:selectOneMenu`

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="empl" value="#{empMB.employee}">
<f:selectItems value="#{empMB.employeeList}" var="emp"
itemLabel="#{emp.employeeName}" itemValue="#{emp.employeeNumber}"/>     
                        <p:ajax update="department"  />                      
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Child `p:selectOneMenu`

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="department" value="#{deptMB.department}">
<f:selectItems value="#{deptMB.loadDepartments(<??>)}" var="dept"
itemLabel="#{dept.departmentName}" itemValue="#{dept.departmentCode}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

I have a method in department ManagedBean called loadDepartments with one argument

```
public void loadDepartments(String employeeNumber)
```

How can I pass value to loadDepartments in child component so that it will load all the departments based on the code selected in parent component?

If I am substituting  `#{deptMB.loadDepartments(empMB.employee.employeeCode)}` I am getting

```
Error Parsing: #{deptMB.loadDepartments({empMB.employee.employeeCode})}
```

Any help is highly appreciable?

Comment: The error indicates you're embedding EL (with "{}" inside another "{}"). EL will process everything within the "#{}" so you don't need the extra braces. That aside, what you're attempting is not a good design. Andre's answer is the better approach. Prepopulate a backing bean list and bind that to the `<f:selectItems/>`

Comment: inside your `empMB`, instead of `private Employee employee`, use `private String employeeNumber` and use it as the value for your 1st `selectOneMenu`. Then you can do `<f:selectItems value="#{deptMB.loadDepartments(empMB.employeeNumber)}" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do this:

1. Add a list variable to your bean (and the appropriate getter): this list will hold the values for the child combo box;
2. Add a listener to the p:ajax call on the parent combo box: the listener populates the list of child values (you'll have access to the selected parent item inside its listener); and
3. Update your xhtml to use the values from the list created on step 1 instead of the loadDepartments method you're trying to invoke.

This is normally how I do this sort of thing and it should work out for you.

**EDIT**

Code for the page:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="empl" value="#{empMB.employee}" converter="#{employeeConverter}">
<f:selectItems value="#{empMB.employeeList}" var="emp" itemLabel="#{emp.employeeName}" itemValue="#{emp.employeeNumber}"/>     
    <p:ajax update="department" listener="#{empMB.onEmployeeSelect}" process="@this"/>                      
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="department" value="#{deptMB.department}" converter="#{departmentConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{empMB.departmentList}" var="dept" itemLabel="#{dept.departmentName}" itemValue="#{dept.departmentCode}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Snippet for the bean:

```
public class EmpMB{
...
private List<Department> departmentList;
private Employee employee;

public List getDepartmentList(){
    return departmentList;
}

public void onEmployeeSelect(){
    departmentList = someService.getDepartmentsForEmployee(employee);
}
...
}
```

Converter sample (note that it's a spring component so that I can inject my service layer into it, but you don't HAVE to do it this way):

```
@Component("employeeConverter")
public class EmployeeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
        //TODO: implement this
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
        //TODO: implement this
    }

}
```

Comment: I figured it was simple enough not to need it, specially given the reputation of the person asking the question, who seems to be a knowledgeable person. But you've got a point. I'll edit the answer in a bit.

Comment: @Andre Appreciate if you could provide some snippets.

Comment: @Polppan done... use that as a starting point and let me know if you need further help

Comment: @Andre One for thing before I begin, do I need a Converter class?

Comment: @Polppan yes, you do. I didn't add it to the code because your question didn't have one. My bad. Do you need help with that too?

Comment: @Andre My selectOneMenu is in a popup dialog. When I run application, popup dialog doesn't open.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24849/discussion-between-andre-and-polppan)